# Is the absolute value of a sequence that converges to $0$ monotone?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to apply Dirichlet's Test in a proof, and I am given that $\sum a_n$ converges, which implies that $a_n\to0$ and $|a_n|\to0$. Can I conclude that there is an $N$ such that $\forall n\geq N$, $|a_n|$ is monotone decreasing?

Answer (score 2):

No, any absolutely convergent series can be rearranged and yield the same sum. So, unless the sequence is constant, you can always rearrange terms to make it not eventually monotone.

Answer (score 1):

No; consider $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$.

edit: even after your edit, no. Consider $a_n = 0$ if $n$ is even and $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Apologies, I meant $|a_n|$ is monotone decreasing.